# Check if letters are match

Tags: assembly, compare

I have a string represented by char *list and the string size is count, I want to change the letter by shifting two positions, and check if it is letter A. I have code like this

```
mov esi, list;
xor ecx, ecx;

loop:
mov ebx, [esi + ecx];
inc ecx;
add ebx, 2; //character shifts two positions
cmp ebx, 0x41;
je end;
cmp ecx, count;
jl loop;

end:
```

I also try

```
mov al, byte[ebx];
cmp al, 0x41;
```

but it does not work either. I wonder how can I compare the letters. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're on the right track with `mov al, [ebx]` which is reading one byte (a single character). Probably, if you did `lea ebx, [esi+ecx]` you would get the right address into `ebx`. Now you are reading 4 characters into `ebx`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Checking for a letter "A" __after__ you shifted by 2, does this mean the string contains something encrypted?

Comment: @Fifoernik yes, this is a encryption problem. Actually I just want to check if the character is still a letter after shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work if you change EBX into BL everywhere. Characters have a 1 byte size.

Like it is written now there is no way to see if the letter A was found or not. Both cases make it to the *end:* label.

LATE CATCH

```
add ebx, 2; //character shifts two positions
```

The usual understanding of shifting is not what you did with this addition!
If you really meant the addition then why not rather compare to a value of (0x41 - 2) ?

If on the other hand shifting really means shifting (SHL or SHR) then the code presented (and corrected through using BL) will never ever produce the letter "A". That is because the bitpattern of "A" which is 0100_0001b simply can not be obtained through **shifting 2 positions** be it to the left or to the right.